# Unicorn 3 - exclude childrenOfPath is slow

Tags: unicorn

Using Unicorn 3.0, In my Unicorn serialisation config I have this:

```
        <include name="Content" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/AAA" >
              <exclude childrenOfPath="Imported Data/BBB/" />
        </include>
```

In the directoryBBB, there are thousands of items and doing a reserialisation is slow as it processes each child item to exclude.

The full path to the imported data folder is /sitecore/content/AAA/Imported Data/BBB/

Is there a quicker way of specifying this in config?

Comment: Could you update your question is full content tree? Or at least how it looks like under /sitecore/content/AAA